# Recursively Report Folder statistics in ADLS Gen 1 - CLI or Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake, azure-cli

I am trying to loop through the directory structure of an ADLS filesystem, reporting each directory's size and format until no further directory exists.

Since the folder structure contains TBs of data, I thought using Azure CLI with PowerShell would be the most efficient way to go about this.

But Gen 1's CLI command is limited to:
`az dls fs list --account <storage_account> --path <path of the file>`

Can I use this command in Powershell to further loop through the rest of the folder structure? Or is there another way to loop through ADLS's folder structure without using the CLI command?

I am a newbie to Azure CLI, hence apologizing if this question is not very advanced.

Comment: Try Power BI Desktop.  I did this successfully against ADLS Gen 2 recently, have not tried Gen 1.  Remove the Binary column and expand the folder attributes for the size.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested in our local environment, Below observations are based on our analysis.

1. We cannot get the accumulated directory size, Irrespective of which
   tools you use like  (ex: portal, storage explorer or  through
   PowerShell cmdlets).

[image]

2. If you use this cmdlet `Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItemSummary` this will give directory count(Number of directories available in this container),file count(total files in all subfolders/directories),length (total size  consumed by all the files in directories & in subfolders).

```html
 $listdir=Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -account '<DataLakeAccountName>' -Path /
    $listarray=$listdir
    
    foreach( $listdir in $listarray)
    {
        Write-Output ("current we are listing the files with "+$listdir.Name);
    
        Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItemSummary -account '<DataLakeAccountName>' -path /$($listdir.Name)
    
     }
```

[image]

- In the above screen shot , directories with names `tried,testing`
  has values 0 since it does have any files or  sub directories.
- The value of directory `trim` is 6 since it is having 2 files under
  track1 sub directory and 4 files under `jshfa` subdirectory.

Alternatively , you can use the below script if you to list the files under the sub directory with there respective sizes.

```html
$listdir=Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -account '<DataLakeAccountName>' -Path /
    $listarray=$listdir
    
    foreach( $listdir in $listarray)
    {
        
       Write-Output ("current we are listing the files under "+$listdir.Name +" "+"length of the Directory is: " + $listdir.length);
       
       $addvar=Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -account '<DataLakeAccountName>' -Path /$($listdir.Name) | Select -Property length,Name,type;
       
       ##Write-Host $addvar;
    
       $subdirect = $addvar; 
    
       ##Write-Host $subdirect;
    
       foreach( $addvar in $subdirect)
       {
        if($addvar.type -eq 'DIRECTORY')
        {
             
          $subfolderlist=Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -account '<DataLakeAccountName>' -Path /$($listdir.Name)/$($addvar.Name);
          Write-Output $subfolderlist
        
        }
       }
       Write-Output $addvar
    }
```

Below is The output of the above script: Here Trim has 2 subdirectories(track1, track234) since track1 has two files and those are listed here & remaining directories, sub-directories doesn't have any files & hence the length value in below output is 0.

[image]

**Note:**
If you have multiple folders under sub-directory every time you need append the directory path in for each loop & make the changes accordingly.

Also both [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/dls/fs?view=azure-cli-latest#az_dls_fs_list), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datalakestore/get-azdatalakestorechilditem?view=azps-6.5.0) Cmdlets both dependents on the given `-path` parameter.